# Xcode build creation errors on Generic iOS Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, llvm

My project is working fine when run in debug mode, on device or simulator.
But when i try to build project for `Generic IOS Device` it gives me 282 errors.
Here is the screenshot:
Some main points are

```
Header 'stdatomic.h' not found
Unknown type name '__BEGIN_DECLS'
Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
Expected function body after function declarator
Unknown type name 'size_t'
Could not build module 'os_object'
Could not build module 'UIKit'
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by general ios device?

Comment: That means target set to General IOS Device instead of Any iPhone or simulator

Comment: general or generic ?

Comment: sorry it is generic

Comment: Did you try Build Clean first? Might help. I also have a frameworks folder where all of my pod code builds into and I need to delete it to clean up some occasional weird errors. Finally, when all else fails restart xcode and your Mac.